# Add Series value in legend for pie charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts.js - I want to add the series value to legend , I don't think i need to use label Formatting function ( I tried using that ). Here is the code currently I have but I am unable see the charts with the below code. I am pretty sure I am doing a small mistake. Can anyone please point out where exactly I am doing mistake.
    $(function () {

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
             legend: {
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                 labelFormat: 
                ' {series.name} + ' ' + {point.percentage:.1f}'
                 ,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Comment: The legend normally contains static text. You are trying to use a point value. Which point do you want to use ? Are you trying to change the legend depending on which point you are hovering over ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it myself. I have to use labelFormatter. Here is the code.

```
  legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            enabled: true,
            floating: true,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                 labelFormatter: function() {
                     return this.name + ' ' +this.percentage;
                 }
                 }
```

Comment: We can use `labelFormat: '{name} {percentage:.1f}%'`

Comment: None of the labelFormat or labelFormatter can work at current version