# Highcharts Pie Chart Add Value to the Legend

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use labelFormat in my Highcharts Pie chart to add the y value of my series to the legend name. I haven't been able to. My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805652/add-series-value-in-legend-for-pie-charts), except I want the actual y value instead of a percentage. Thank you for your time.

Here's what I have so far, except I don't want percentage. I want the actual value:

```
legend: {
        labelFormat: '{name} ({percentage:.0f})',
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code instead, where `2f` is a number of decimals value:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ukc1tf3p/

```
legend: {
  labelFormat: '{name} {y:.2f}',
},
```

API: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#format-strings